# Spring Cloud Vault does not Refer to Application Name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a property shown below:

```yaml
spring.application.name: some-app
spring.cloud.vault:
  host: ${VAULT_HOST:localhost}
  port: ${VAULT_PORT:8200}
  scheme: ${VAULT_SCHEME:http}
  fail-fast: true
  authentication: TOKEN
  token: ${VAULT_TOKEN}
  kv:
    application-name: some-app
    enabled: ${VAULT_ENABLE:true}
    backend: secret/config
```

while the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/docs/current/reference/html/#client-side-usage) states that it will refer to these four:

- /secret/{application}/{profile}
- /secret/{application}
- /secret/{default-context}/{profile}
- /secret/{default-context}

but for some reason, my app is showing this error message. Why does it refer to secret/config/application? Why doesn't it refer to secret/config/some-app instead? I've placed in both spring.application.name and spring.cloud.vault.kv.application-name and still no result

```
2024-02-19 18:58:16 [main] INFO  o.s.v.c.e.LeaseAwareVaultPropertySource  : Vault location [secret/config/application] not resolvable: Not found
```

Comment: `{application}` gets replaced with `some-app` and `{default-context}` gets replaced with `application` by default

Comment: won't it be confusing if the app refers to both /secret/application and /secret/default-context? I don't see how it differs. 
Say I'm trying to store under /secret/config/some-app.

I also tried this:

    `backend: secret`\n`default-context: config` \n`application-name: some-app`

but for some reason now it picks secret/some-app and not secret/config/some-app. Really need help here I'm lost with the 4 patterns shown above

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I got it. So I thought the previous message was an error so I panicked.

The actual behaviour as I can comprehend it is as follows:

```
/secret/{application}/{profile} -> Configuration for your specific app + profile
/secret/{application} -> Configuration for your specific app
/secret/{default-context}/{profile} -> Configuration for multiple apps + profile
/secret/{default-context} -> Configuration for multiple apps
```

So when I placed:

```yaml
backend: secret/config
application-name: some-app
```

Spring Config still picks 2 things, /secret/config/some-app & /secret/config/application. And, if the default context "application" is missing, that's fine!